# Meaning of `:=` Syntax in VBA methods

Tags: vba, syntax, syntax-error, named-parameters, colon-equals

When writing the following VBA, what is the root cause of the error "Expected =" given that we are using the `Format:=2`.

`Workbook.Open (filename, Format:=2)`

I understand that this format works when setting the variable as in the following code, but why does it work here and not in the above format?

`Set wrkb = Workbook.Open (filename, Format:=2)`

Also what is this operator called, `:=` and how is it used?

Comment: just use `Set wrkb = Workbook.Open (filename)` , where `filename` is a String consists of the full path and filename (including the file extension, liks ".xlsx")

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Could you clarify why the Set method works and the other does not? I am interested in understanding the syntax, not just rote memorization. Thanks

Comment: you can just **Google** it, link to MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link. I did google it and there is no explanation on the rationale for ":=" and using the set method. Please reference where they say anything about this in the link you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an operator, it's a named argument.

You can chose the order of the arguments/parameters by directly specifying what they are.

The concept of named arguments also exists in multiple modern languages, such as c# (its optional, just like in VBA) and swift (by default it's required, but you can disable it).

Named arguments also allow you to omit arguments that are optional altogether, but pass an argument that is further back in the list of arguments. A good way to try named arguments out is the messagebox, since it has many optional arguments with default values.

Example: MsgBox only specifying title:

```
MsgBox Title:="wew lad"
```

Or, in the more modern way of writing vb(a) code:

```
Call MsgBox(Title:="wew lad")
```

The MsgBox is a good example, since you can call it normally, and then specify a parameter further back directly (works with other methods too):

```
 Call MsgBox("Yes!", Title:="wew lad")
```

Once there are named parameters, you can't add ordered parameters after:

```
'Call MsgBox (Prompt:="Yes!", vbOkCancel  Title:="wew lad")
'this doesnt work!
```

Now, why does this raise an error:

```
MsgBox ("Hello", Title:="test")
```

This is some of the weirder parts of vba. Calling functions with return values but ignoring the value while using **parentheses** is a bit broken.

You can circumvent this by adding a `Call` in front of it (vba then knows it can ignore the result).

This would look like this:

```
Call MsgBox ("Hello", Title:="test")
```

Honestly, I don't know why this is, but I've had it cause really weird bugs. *When you use the parentheses syntax*, I can really recommend using the `Call` keyword before the method call.

As Macro Man mentioned, you can also omit the parentheses, instead of using `Call`:

```
MsgBox "Hello", Title:="test"
```

And it will work, too. This was the original vba coding style and isn't really used anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mafii, do you know why it only works when setting the variable as in the code in the question?

Comment: Do you mean this:? `Set wrkb = Workbook.Open (filename, Format:=2)`

Comment: You can mix normal parameters with named parameters. Ill add an explanation

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clarification. `MsgBox ("Hello", Title:="test")` interestingly does not work by itself due to the syntax not accepting the parentheses. Any idea why this is the case? Yet `MsgBox ("Hello")` does work.

Comment: You need a `Call` before it. I don't know why, vba seems to work in mysterious ways here. `Call MsgBox ("Yes!", Title:="wew lad")` def. works

Comment: `Or, in the more modern way of writing vb(a) code:` Actually, the `Call` keyword is just there for legacy purposes and has no use in 'modern' VBA code. The reason you have to use it in your example is because you have used parentheses around the arguments. Unless you are assigning to a variable, there is no need to use parentheses in this way and it can actually have adverse effects.

Comment: `MsgBox "Hello", Title:="test"` will work just fine, adding `Call` to the start of something because you've used parentheses where they aren't needed is **not** a fix

Comment: @MacroMan I removed the word "fix" since I agree with you. However, op was asking why it doesnt work, I explained, and showed how it does work. You shouldn't omit the parantheses since this is bad practice, old style, and a source of mistakes and a source of problems. Totally agree with the use of the word "fix" tho.

Comment: @Mafii Do you actually know _why_ the parentheses break the code? If not then you shouldn't assume that this is "old style" which very much isn't the case. Newer .NET languages require this style of coding but VBA doesn't - and omitting parentheses where they aren't required is **not** bad practice - the parentheses do actually have a valid purpose, and in this example they aren't required - so adding them in unnecessarily is actually bad practice.

Comment: @MacroMan this depends on what you consider bad practice, the reason why I (and many others) don't omit the parantheses is because of the fact that if you call methods sometimes this way, sometimes that way, it gets inconsistent, and hard to read. I agree the parantheses are not new, but I've never seen newer vba code that doesn't use them, and it confuses developers that dont use vba often. Its all up to preference, but using `Call` and parantheses is a good consistent standard imho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122375/discussion-between-macro-man-and-mafii).